# Using Raphaël from a jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm trying to create a simple application for drawing a graph based on user input. I'm using Raphaël and jQuery. I'd like to have the user give their input on a form, and then draw the SVG graphic. The problem I'm having is that when I call the draw function from within a jQuery click event, the SVG object flickers and then disappears. There's a MWE below. (Perhaps it could be more minimal.) How can I make sure that the graphic stays there after the button click?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<button id="generate-button">Generate</button>
</form>

<div id="canvas"/>

<script>
function CustomObject() {
    this.draw = function() {
        // Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
        paper = Raphael("canvas", 100, 100 );

        boundary = window.paper.rect( 5, 5, 25, 25 );
        boundary.attr("stroke-dasharray" , "--" );

        // Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
        circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
        // Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
        circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

        // Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
        circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
    }
}

var plot = new CustomObject();
// plot.draw(); // if I call it here, the scene is drawn "normally"

$( "#generate-button" )
    .button()
        .click(function() {
            plot.draw(); // when I call it here, the SVG flickers and disappears
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is only one click event happening ?

Comment: Yeah. If I put an alert in the .click() handler it only pops up once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type for a button is submit and when inside a form will try to submit the form.

Your click handler is executing and then submitting the form which is causing the flicker.

Either take the button out of the form or return false from the click event handler as this will disable the browsers default action.